# Background Image not working on site, returns error

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

Background image seems to not work as expected.

The output:
[**See here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VTZV.jpg)

Github repo for looking into: https://www.github.com/vishalscodes/shashiks (Files are deployed from the _site folder)

Website: https://shashiks.netlify.app

This doesn't seem to work even with the url() function and it doesn't return any error in the console, which is what I generally use to solve these problems.

PS - Please don't mind my Question framing (Stack Overflow returns too many errors for the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your CSS variable to the following. Use `url()` instead of `image()`

```
--youtube-bg-image: url(/img/youtube-logo.jpg);
```

Also, you had a typo in your image extension. You used .jpeg instead of .jpg

Comment: Okay, so I had done the changes as given. This is my code snippet: `:root {
  --youtube-bg-image: url("img/youtube-logo.jpg");
}` and `.youtube-product-section::before,
.youtube-product-section::after {
  content: "";
  background: var(--youtube-bg-image);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}`. Still the issue persists though.

Comment: @vishalscodes u didnt put the "/" (slash) before "img/youtube-logo.jpg". Because of this, the final url becomes "https://shashiks.netlify.app/css/img/youtube-logo.jpg". By putting slash("/"), the path becomes "https://shashiks.netlify.app/img/youtube-logo.jpg"